# iOS facebook integration methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

I'm just after some pointers on the method that can get the best results for integrating **FB** into an iphone app.  Obviously **iOS6** social api wont work on older devices - that is something I can live with if the social api does most of what I want.  If not, I'd like to know what **FB** api kit should be used instead.  The features I would like are:

1. Ability to post into a users own timeline.
2. Ability to check in & tag others
   In both cases I would like the post to a link to another website and a link people can use to download the app that did the posting.

For example Run Keeper comes up nicely branded with activities in peoples time line - thats what I'm after although I'm not sure that Run Keeper links to where the app can be downloaded.

Is it nessacary to implement a **FaceBook** app to deliver any of this functionality or can it all be done from the iOS side?

Many thanks
Josh

Answer (score 3):

Go with the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/), this will detect [iOS 6](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/) and use the native methods.
If there is no support native support, iOS 5 or lower, it will allow the user to login via the web or if setup correctly the Facebook App.

You can then take full advantage of the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) which does allow you to do more than just post new wallposts.

When doing a [Checkin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/) or a [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) you can tag people.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook implementation in Ios6 and add a **framework** **social.Framework** ..hope your helpfull

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
   ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    ACAccount *account = [[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:accountType];
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", account.username, account.description);
}];

if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

            NSLog(@"Cancelled");

        } else

        {
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }

        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    };
    controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

    [controller setInitialText:@"Test Post from mobile.safilsunny.com"];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com"]];
    [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.png"]];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
else{
    NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
}
```